# Good book to learn Java (focused on enterprise) on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, javabeans

I'm a .net developer, and I have worked the last 8 years with Microsoft technologies... but in one month I will begin to work with Java on Eclipse. I don't know both well. I've been following the java learning path but I prefer to learn with a book, but there are millions of them.

The most important point for me are:
- Web services
- desktop aplications and deployment

Do you have any recommendation for me? Thanks!

Comment: Hi! The question was constructive for me. In my companie we have access to the chat of Stack Overflow and this is the only way I have to ask something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have 8 years programming experience, so I think Thinking in java And Effective in Java are enough for u.

Thinking in java make u familiar with Java syntax And Effective in Java helps u understand how to use java correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look! One question: Effective in Java is Jens Bloch's "Effective Java"? This was my first option but I would like to know if I will learn how to set my development environment as well.

Comment: @Rafa sorry,I make a mistake,it should be "Effective Java".If u would like to know how to set your development,I suggest u google it,  it is easy for u to find the answer and learn how to use eclipse effectively

Comment: OK, thanks, you're right, and maybe I even need one book for Java and another to learn eclipse basics. (I like books :))

Answer (score 1):

When looking for entreprise patterns in general this one is a true standard :

http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html

It might only cover a part for what you are looking for, but a vital part.

Comment: Thank you, I already own this book ;) I love it, but my problem is far more basic... I don't even know how to set a breakpoint on eclipse or how to set a project or what do I expect as output when I compile... I know it sounds strange but I never had any contact to the java world even if I can read java (from design patterns books or similar) but I have no real "hands on" experience with it! :(